# Ionic 4 Ion-Menu maintain state like tabs

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-routing

In Ionic you can have some tabs. If you edit content (say an input or click a link) on view 1 (tab 1), then go to view 2 (tab 2) and back to tab 1, you will still have that content edited. It's switching between loaded views. However, with ion-menu, each time you click on a menu it's a new navigation. So switching between view 1 and view 2 will reset all states. Is there a way to have ion-menu act like ionic tabs?

I am using Ionic 4 with Angular Router

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I did not unfortunately.

Comment: I did work out a solution, I'll update as soon as I have it written up nicely.